# Modify XPSingle ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have successfully and rather easily deployed the XPSingle environment found here:  https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.0.2/XPSingle.  Pretty pleased with it overall!

However, now I want to modify my ARM template to separate the CD server into a separate App Service - while leaving CM, Reporting, Processing on the first.

Is it as simple as modifying the WDP for Single to remove the CD role, and then adding the appropriate one for CD - and adding the correct resources to the azuredeploy.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required things to do:

- Adapt WDP to remove CD role
- Create a seperate WDP with just the CD role
- Modify the nested/application.json to deploy the new cd

Optionaly you might want to adapt infrastructure.json to create a seperate appserviceplan for your cd.

You could also inverse the method by starting from the XP-Scaled and then bundling the reporting and processing onto the cm.

Comment: Your bullets are actually the route I ended up going.  However, I tried to modify the azuredeploy.json to add a new source for the CD role, and the armtemplate is throwing a fit.  I'm guessing I'll have to roll my own for that.

Comment: I marked your response as the answer because it confirmed my path.  I essentially ended up with the following:
1.  Modify infrastructure.json to include a new hosting plan and app service
2.  Modify the XP CD package to remove database scripts, update the web.config
3.  Add a deploy of #2 to the application.json
4.  Profit. :)